# PHP inserting value for attributes that should not have value

Tags: php

I am using the Foundation 5 framework for my view and a funny thing happens when I echo some Foundation elements that have valueless attributes.

Example:

```
echo "dl class='accordion'  id='accordionBlock' data-accordion"
```

generates this HTML:

```
dl class="accordion" id="accordionBlock" data-accordion=""
```

Why is PHP `concatenating =""` ? This is happening in every instance. It's not having a terribly detrimental effect as far as things working or not....it's just weird. Whats up?

Comment: Maybe browser does this?

Comment: php does not do it. Anything else, that parses the string as elements with attributes - can. Because `data-accordion` is an empty attribute, and every attribute should have a value, even empty one. Browser also do it this way to follow the standards.

Comment: Yep, I blame the browser, too. Check your browser's Network activity (in dev tools) to see the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not PHP fault.
Browser add this marker.

This happened because 'data-' attribute has special meaning in HTML.
Every attribute 'data-*' that is declared but not set (no '=' operator).
Browser will interper like empty ("") value.

Declaration:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionBlock" data-accordion>test</div>
```

Is similar to this one:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionBlock" data-accordion="">test</div>
```

Here you can find more info: 
[HTML data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Comment: Yeah it was Firfox that did it, Chrome does not but now I have some issues w/ Chrome and things not working there